# Object.respond_to? fails when retrieving method name symbol from array

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, reflection, testunit

I'm implementing page objects, and writing tests to verify them. I want to simplify the tests by storing the element names in an array of symbols and looping through it, but it's failing.

```
def setup
  @browser = Watir::Browser.new :phantomjs
  @export_page = ExportPage.new @browser
  @assets = %i{:section :brand}
end
```

--

```
#PASSES

def test_static
    $stdout.puts :section.object_id
    raise PageElementSelectorNotFoundException, :section unless @export_page.respond_to? :section
end

> # 2123548
```

This passes because the target class does implement this method, however:

```
#FAILS

def test_iterator
  @assets.each do |selector|
    $stdout.puts selector.class
    $stdout.puts selector.object_id
    $stdout.puts :section.object_id
    raise PageElementSelectorNotFoundException, selector unless @export_page.respond_to? selector
  end
end


> # Testing started at 11:19 ...
> # Symbol
> # 2387188
> # 2123548

PageElementSelectorNotFoundException: :section missing from page
~/src/stories/test/pages/export_page_test.rb:20:in `block in test_iterator'
```

As you can see, I've checked the object ids of the symbols and they do seem to be different. Could this be why it's failing? Is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using short notation to declare an array of atoms, one should not put colons there:

```
- %i{:section :brand}   # incorrect
+ %i{section brand}     # correct
```

What you have actually defined by `@assets = %i{:section :brand}`, is the following array:

```
[:':section', :':brand']
```

Comment: Thanks. It was a schoolboy error wasn't it?

I'm going to select this one because it's a more concise answer and it encourages idiomatic Ruby.

Comment: I would consider it being more of a typo than of a schoolboy error :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the %i{} notation, because it automatically makes a symbol of the literal(s) that you specify.

This translates to:

```
@assets = [:":section", :":brand"]
```

which is technically an array of symbols, just not the symbols that you intended.  This is why the object IDs don't match in your tests.

The %i{} syntax was added in Ruby 2.0.  When used in code that may support for older Ruby versions, use a traditional array of symbols:

```
@assets = [:section, :brand]
```

Comment: Your answer contains: wrong advise to not use `%i`, syntax error in the only LOC you provided and besides that it is a shallow copy of mine. I wonder what was the reason of posting it?

Comment: @mudasobwa I didn't copy your answer because it didn't exist when I started writing my answer.

Comment: I never said you have anything _explicitly copied_, I said that when it was posted, it appeared to be a copy. OK, you fixed a syntax error, please, at least, remove a _wrong_ advise to not use `%i` in favour of `[:section, :brand]`, that violates ruby idiomatic concepts as well as basic common sense.